# Use of login_hint in the API client library

Tags: google-api-java-client

I'm using the 1.20 version of the API library to handle OAuth flows for a web server app.  Based on https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer, there is a login_hint parameter that can be passed-in to the flow to simplify user selection.  I've incorporated this into my authorization servlet, and it seems to work.  However, looking through the source for the library on GitHub, I don't see any reference to this parameter.  Am I missing something?  Shouldn't it be exposed in the API?  It's a big help to simplify the flow for end-users.

While I'm making helpful suggestions, it would also be nice to simplify the way state information is passed-in to the flow.  Very convoluted for something that is required for most flows.  As far as I can tell, the current way to pass-in parameters involves building a temporary flow to get a URL, injecting parameters into that URL, and then using that URL to build the real flow.

Not to mention that it would be nice if AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet.initializeFlow() were passed the request - as it stands now, I have to override the service() method to get the request.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Since this is really more of a feature request for the API, and I'm not really looking for a solution (unless I'm off-base), I'll mark this as answered.

Edit:

Just to add some actual value to this, vs. my "helpful" comments, here is the substance of my initializeFlow() method, in case it helps anyone:

```java
final GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder builder = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
    "client-ID",
    "client-secret",
    "scopes...");
final GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = builder.build();
final GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl();

url.setState("base-64-encoded-state...");
url.put("login_hint", "bozo@clown.com");

return builder
    .setAuthorizationServerEncodedUrl(url.build())
    .setAccessType("offline")
    .setApprovalPrompt("force")
    .build();
```

Comment: Is it possible to inject the e-mail to be used somehow? Obviously it would be different for each user...